# Alert Dialog in ViewModel - MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

In the `ViewModel`, I have `Save` method where I check `isValid` property.

If `isValid` is `false`, then I want to display an error message.

Since `AlertDialog` is platform specific, I wonder how do you handle that situation in the `ViewModel`?

```
public void Save()
{
  if (isValid)
  {
      OnExit(this, null);
   }
   else
   {
      //issue an alert dialog here
   }
}
```

**Update**

I have used the following [plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chance.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction/) and added the following line of code as follows, but it throws an error.

```
else
{
    Mvx.Resolve<IUserInteraction>().Alert("it is not valid");
}
```

[image]

**Update 2**

`Chance.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction` is a namespace but it is used as a type error.

[image]

**Update 3**

I have added **Acr.UserDialogs** plugin and called as follows, but I have got the same error.

```
Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert("it is not valid");
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add the nuget to the Android and iOS projects as well ?

Comment: Yes I have added PCL, Android and iOS. I could able to see `Chance.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction.Droid` and `Chance.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction` in the Android Solution

Comment: I just noticed that the Mvvmcross plugin has not been kept up to date and some dependencies can not be resolved. I would suggest you use a different plugin: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs  You can also find a full list of xamarin plugins here:https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Do you get an exception when attempting to display the alert ? anything in the log ? I am sure you already did this but did you register IUserDialog in the app.cs in the PCL project ? Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserDialogs>(() => UserDialogs.Instance);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [ACR User Dialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/) is the simplest approach.

In your App.cs (Core/PCL) you will need to register the interface:

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
       // Example Other registrations
        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserDialogs>(() => UserDialogs.Instance);
    }
}
```

Then you can call your alert form your ViewModel.

```
Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert("it is not valid");
```

**Note for Android Platform support**

Then if you are supporting Android you will need to initialize UserDialog with an instance of the activity context. This will have to be done in each activity that you will be making use of `UserDialogs` or if you have a shared base activity you can do it there.

```
[Activity]
public class MainActivity : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize Acr UserDialogs
        UserDialogs.Init(this);
    }
}
```

**Alternatively**

You can follow the [Mvvmcross document](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/inversion-of-control-ioc#section-how-do-i-use-ioc-when-i-need-different-implementations-on-different-platforms-) on using platform specific implementations of an interface if you need a more custom modal implementation.

Comment: If I need to use it in the iOS,         `UserDialogs.Init(this);`
needs to go where?

Comment: @hotspring, nope iOS requires no additional actions :)

Comment: iOS and Windows = "Nothing is necessary any longer as of v4.x" [Github](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs#ios-and-windows)

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: Android requires in main activity: 
`UserDialogs.Init(() => Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity)`. 
See [Setup section on GitHub](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs#setup)

Answer (score 4):

This is how I handle the Alert messages in the viewmodel. Try this.

```
await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Active subscription required", "You do not have an active subscription for Part 2 exams", "OK");
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate `Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("xxxx");` ?

Comment: This is a built-in xamarin forms method in Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll that you should be able to simply reach from your viewmodel by just typing the code that I wrote above. This built-in xamarin forms method presents an alert dialog to the application user with a single cancel button. For more details and some more sample code [please see this link.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/pop-ups/)

Comment: When I type `App`, then `App.` does not show any options in my case. It only shows `Reference` or `Equals` property.

Comment: I have just created a new test Xamarin Portable app and I can reach the method without doing anything else. please see below;

Comment: [This is the documentation to create a xamarin portable app](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) and here is my test app's code that I just created. `public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            
            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Test Title", "Test Message", "Cancel text");
        }`

Comment: @hotspring is this a Xamarin.Forms app, if not the displayalert() won't be available unless you implement your own!

Comment: It is not a Xamarin.Form application.

Answer (score 2):

There is an existing MvvmCross plugin called User Interaction that allows displaying alerts and collecting inputs from ViewModels.

From the author BrianChance:

> Really simple, easy, beautiful ways to show a message box or to collect user input from your ViewModels

[Check it out here](https://github.com/brianchance/MvvmCross-UserInteraction) and NuGet Link [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chance.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction/).

To install the plugin, make sure you override LoadPlugins in your SetUp Class on iOS and Android (and windows phone) like so:

```
public override void LoadPlugins(MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins.IMvxPluginManager pluginManager)
{
    base.LoadPlugins(pluginManager);
    pluginManager.EnsurePluginLoaded<Chance.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction>();

}
```

Comment: I have added that plugin and run the app and received an error. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is that i use an event for this scenario. My base class for my view models has a EventHandler OnUserNotification, where the views can kinda subscribe to. The UserNotificationType is just an enum and i let the view kinda decide how it reacts to the situation.

The property:

```
public EventHandler<UserNotificationType> OnUserNotification { get; set; }
```

The call:

```
 if (OnUserNotification != null)
 {
   OnUserNotification.Invoke(this, UserNotificationType.ENetworkError);
 }
```

In the view:

```
private void onUserNotification(object sender, UserNotificationType userNotificationType)
{
     // Do Something like showing a Snackbar, AlertDialog, etc...
}
```

Of course you can make the eventtype more complex if needed.

Didnt try the plugin which got suggested by wishmaster though, so that might be a smoother implementation?

Comment: What am I supposed to put in the `else` condition ? could you please provide a little bit more information?

Comment: If you mean your else condition, you would use OnUserNotification.Invoke(this, UserNotificationType.EExampleError). And then you can handle the notification event in the view. Just be sure that the view attaches the method to the Eventhandler with ViewModel.OnUserNotification += onUserNotification; or whatever your method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Use Acr.UserDialogs.  There is a great examples on [github](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs)

You can grab it on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/)

It works well with dependency injection or a static singleton UserDialogs.Instance